# Insert ActiveX Control Into Powerpoint slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint, activex

I'd like to insert a custom ActiveX control into a Powerpoint slide. I've created the custom control and registered it, and tested that it works. I can easily add the custom control to a UserForm, but can't add it directly to the slide (as per the other controls under Developer Tab -> Controls).

Is it possible to add the custom ActiveX control directly to the slide?

If not, is it possible to embed the UserForm directly to the slide?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to add the control from the `Developer --> More Controls --> register custom`?

Comment: Tried exactly that. I get no errors when I register the control this way, but it is still not available from the "More Controls" menu after registration.

Comment: Seems, you have to provide more details about your custom control, for example: what kind of control it is, what tool you used to create it and register it. I'd suggest to read this: [Using a VS2008 Custom Control in VBA (NOT VB)](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/167323/Using-a-VS-Custom-Control-in-VBA-NOT-VB) and this: [Adding Custom Controls to the Control Toolbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/adding-custom-controls-to-the-control-toolbox)

Answer (score 1):

I'm kind of guessing here, but it's worth giving it a shot. When you registered your ActiveX Control, I'm assuming you assigned a Program ID along with it, correct? If you did, then you might be able to add it as a shape object to the slide you specify. **When you add a shape, you can add specific types of shapes, including OLEObjects.**

For example, in the code below, I add an ActiveX ComboBox Control to Slide 1 in the Active Presentation using PowerPoint VBA. The critical thing to note is that the ProgID identifies the object being inserted.

```
Sub ActiveXControlAdd()

'Declare your variables.
Dim PPTPres As Presentation
Dim PPTSld As Slide
Dim PPTShp As Shape

'Grab the slide you want it on.
Set PPTPres = ActivePresentation
Set PPTSld = PPTPres.Slides(1)

'Add a shape, but make sure it's an OLEObject. Also, CLASSNAME is the ProgID!
Set PPTShp = PPTSld.Shapes.AddOLEObject(Left:=100, Top:=100, Width:=150, Height:=50, ClassName:="Forms.ComboBox.1")

'Print it out to make sure.
Debug.Print PPTShp.OLEFormat.ProgID

End Sub
```

Give it a try and see if that maybe fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want to insert ActiveX control to PowerPoint slide:

> Go to File > Options > Customize Ribbon

On the second column, tick the "Developer" tab.

After you tick it you should see a "Developer" tab in PowerPoint; click on it.

The 3rd and 4th column is where the ActiveX controls are:

[image: The Developer Tab]

For example:

You want to insert a textbox.
You click on the icon that says "abc", next to the big "A".
Then you place it on your slide just like you would place a shape. Click & drag.